# Spring boot Security не работает аутентификация

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Я новенький в java и Spring недавно начал его изучать. решил сделать аутентификацию на своём тестовом сайте с помощью UserDetailsService. Но она не работает. Постоянно пишет, что такого пользователя нет в базе данных mysql. В модели User и Enum'е roles я

Код UserService:

```java
package com.IDS.LinkStack.services;

import com.IDS.LinkStack.domain.User;
import com.IDS.LinkStack.repos.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Collections;

import static com.IDS.LinkStack.domain.Role.USER;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public Boolean saveUser(User user){
        user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        if(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null)
            return false;
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(USER));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```java
package com.IDS.LinkStack.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import com.IDS.LinkStack.services.UserService;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/images/**", "/signup", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

User Model

```java
package com.IDS.LinkStack.domain;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Link> links = new ArrayList<Link>();

    private User(){}
    public User(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public List<Link> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public void setLinks(List<Link> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

}
```

Role enum

```java
package com.IDS.LinkStack.domain;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    USER;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

true
UserDetails
если нет токена в форме csrf().disable